# deriving joint density of $X, W$ while knowing joint density of $X, Y$ where $X + W = Y$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

Joint density of $X,Y$ is 
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = a^2e^{-ay},$$

and I know that $X + W = Y$, where $0 < x < y < \infty$

I want to determine the joint density of $X$ and $W$. I know I can let $X = X$, $W = Y - X$, can through calculate the Jacobian and through solving the following equation, I can get the density of $X$ and $W$:
$$f_{Y_1,Y_2}(y_1, y_2) = \frac{f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1, x_2)}{|\mathcal J (x_1, x_2)|}$$ 
where $x_1 = h_1(y_1, y_2), x_2 = h_2(y_1, y_2)$

However, I am confused in terms of determining the region $X$, and $W$. I know $0<x<y$, which means that $0< x < x+w$. I can get $w > 0$, but I am confused in terms of determining the upper region of $X$. Is it just $x >0$? But $X$ also needs to be smaller than $X + W$?

Comment: It seems like your joint density function does not integrate to 1, since there is no clear dependence on x. Maybe you should also multiply the joint distribution with the characteristic function of where it is defined, to make the question clearer.